# Is there a way to automate creating a PyQt form using JSON schema?

Tags: json, forms, pyqt, pyside, jsonschema

I am working on a GUI (`PyQt6`) where the user loads some files and adds metadata for each. So for each file, I would like to have a window (`QDialog`) which is essentially a form with fields which are specified by a `json` schema.

I am new to `PyQt` and I can code the mechanism to open a form (`QDialog` with `QLabels` and `QLineEdit` which essentially looks like a form. see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs7e6.png)). However, I would like to automatize this step using the schema that's stored in a `json` file (consider any [example `json` schema](http://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html)).

Is there already a python library for this and I'm absolutely obvious about it?
How would you go about coding this? Thanks!

Comment: Please include any attempts you have already made and what you are stuck on.

Comment: if you can't find any solution then last approach would be to create your own little rendering engine that creates the widgets(QLineEdit, QRadioButton) according to the json data read..